# plot entire time series in SAS?

Tags: sas, forecasting

I am trying to make a forecast, and I want to see the entire time series, with the forcasted period at the end (need to compare with another graph of this kind).

SAS 9.4 does not want to comply, however, and only shows me the forecasting part.

What can I do to remedy this?

The code I'm using is:

```
Proc arima data=logtabell;

identify var=y(12) nlag=24;

estimate p=1 q=2;

forecast lead=12 interval=month id=date out=results;

run;
```

Comment: For questions on `SAS`, it is always a good idea to create example code using data from example datasets you find in the `SASHELP` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS procedures have an out=*resultSet* option, from which you can get the results in a dataset.
Combine this output with your time serious in one graph created with `proc sgplot`

Answer (score 2):

Your `out=` dataset will contain all values by default. If you want to specifically see the full graph that it outputs, add the `plots` option:

```
proc arima data=logtabell plots=forecast(forecast);
```

Or, just do it the easy way by getting every plot:

```
proc arima data=logtabell plots = all;
```

Also, make sure `ods graphics on;` is set.